# Showing all data points in Datdog histogram

Tags: c#, histogram, datadog

I'm sending metrics from a C# web service to datadog. I need to track the length of words that are being searched in an api call and display this in a histogram. But datadog is averaging these values which is not what I want. If one string is 1 character in length and another string is 10 characters in length it records a metric of 5.5, which isn't much use to me. Ideally I would like a histogram graph over a time period e.g. an hour, showing the number of instances of 1, 2, 3 etc. that were recorded during that time period. Is that possible in datadog?

This is the call I'm making in the code:

```
_metrics.Histogram<int>(LENGTH_STRING_SEARCH, word.Length, tags: statsdTags);
```

Answer (score 1):

When submitting histograms via dogstatsD you should be automatically creating 5 metrics as shown here:

dog.histogram(...)

Usage: Used to track the statistical distribution of a set of values over a statsd flush period.
Actually submits as multiple metrics:

```
name | Web App type
-----|------------
metric.max | GAUGE
metric.avg | GAUGE
metric.median | GAUGE
metric.95percentile | GAUGE
metric.count | RATE
```

Additional details on metric types and their submission sources can be found here:

https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/206955236-Metric-types-in-Datadog

It appears for your use case `metric.count` would be the closest match for calculating the total length of your word.  Once selected, you can make use of the `as_count()` modifier which will calculate the total count rather than the average over the flushing period.  More information on this use case can be found here:

https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/204271195-Why-is-a-counter-metric-being-displayed-as-a-decimal-value-

If you find yourself still running into any issues with this submission feel free to reach out to support@datadoghq.com

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried the count metric but it seems it just displays the number of metrics that are being sent at the moment rather than the value. E.g. is the follow values are sent 1, 5, 3, 10, 6 then the count shows a value of 5 (as there were 5 metrics).

Comment: Interesting.  Can you email support@datadoghq.com and they can review your account and the data points stored to see if there is a discrepancy.

Comment: My account is working as intended. Count is supposed to track the frequency that a metric if logged, not for an analysis of the value that contained within each occurrence:
https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/visualize-statsd-metrics-counts-graphing/